# Problem with Assert.equal

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I am compiling the code available at using "truffle test":

https://michalzalecki.com/ethereum-test-driven-introduction-to-solidity/

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/Funding.sol";

contract FundingTest {
   function testSettingAnOwnerDuringCreation() public {
      Funding funding = new Funding();
      Assert.equal(funding.owner(), this, "An owner is different than  deployer");
   }

}
```

I am getting the following message:

> $ truffle test
>
> You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js versions older
> than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your
> project Using network 'test'.
>
> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
>
> > Compiling ./test/FundingTest.sol
>
> /FundingTest.sol:8:7:
> TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert).
> Assert.equal(funding.owner(), this, "An owner is different than  deployer");
> ^----------^
>
> Compilation failed. See above. Truffle v5.1.27 (core: 5.1.27) Node
> v8.10.0

Comment: Try `Assert.equal(funding.owner(), assert(this), ....)`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, I am trying to upgrade to latest version v5.1.33.

Comment: Do you have a version ready to test? I tried with the article repo https://github.com/MichalZalecki/tdd-solidity-intro, but it is very old and I can't make it work without spending too much time fixing things required by the migration from 0.4 to 0.5. I saw that many of your questions came from reading old articles, perhaps you can try some of the truffle boxes, they are more recent https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/pet-shop but you still may find some bugs from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I started with pet-shop. The example works. But it does not have any example related to reentrancy. Okay I would try one of the improved versions on it.

Comment: I tried the update v5.1.33 but it did not work.

Comment: @zak100 did you find any solution? I'm running into this issue now, using truffle v5.3.7

Comment: Yes, assert.equal(..) does not work with compilation. It will work with test.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena please see the link: https://michalzalecki.com/ethereum-test-driven-introduction-to-solidity/